# How to format the week number to a desired format in H2

Tags: java, date, timestamp, h2, week-number

I want a date format with week number and year in the ISO format of yyyy-'W'ww. However, with only week function available in H2 database, I am able to get only the week number without the year. How can I format in such a way that I add a default year to it. Something like 2016-'W'ww.

Currently, I am using this function (which is definitely not the correct way)

> WEEK(PARSEDATETIME(TRUNC(" + this.fieldName + "),'2016ww')
>   WEEK(PARSEDATETIME(TRUNC(" + this.fieldName + "),'2016-ww')

I am not able to get what else can be done. Can anyone help me here

Comment: What exactly is the data type and content of `this.fieldName`?

Comment: It is the column name. Let's say 'Time' having the data type 'DATE'

Comment: Clarifications should be posted as edits to your Questions rather than as comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are several valid solutions in different libraries. However, you need to know that using the standard calendar year "y" would be wrong. Instead you have to **use the year-of-weekdate** (or called weekbased year) with symbol "Y" (capital letter).

**Example using old `Calendar`-stuff**:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(2017 - 1900, 0, 1); // 2017-01-01
GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
gcal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
gcal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
gcal.setTime(sqlDate);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-'W'ww");
System.out.println(sdf.format(gcal.getTime())); // 2016-W52
```

---

**Example using Java-8:**

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(2017 - 1900, 0, 1); // 2017-01-01

LocalDate ld = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-'W'ww", Locale.FRANCE);
System.out.println(dtf.format(ld)); // 2016-W52
```

Side note: I have here chosen the locale of France to ensure the correct week configuration needed for ISO-8601.

---

**Example using my library [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/CalendarWeek.html)** which is only interesting and gives a surplus value if you also plan to do some arithmetic with obtained calendar week (like `plusWeeks(5)` or plan to get some styled localized output):

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(2017 - 1900, 0, 1); // 2017-01-01
PlainDate value = JDBCAdapter.SQL_DATE.translate(sqlDate);
CalendarWeek cw =
    CalendarWeek.of(
        value.get(PlainDate.YEAR_OF_WEEKDATE),
        value.get(Weekmodel.ISO.weekOfYear())
    );
System.out.println(cw.toString()); // 2016-W52
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek                       // Handy class found in the ThreeTen-Extra library added to your project.
.from(                                            // Determine the week number and the week-based year number from the passed `LocalDate` object, according to standard ISO 8601 definition of a week.
    myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class )  // Produces a `LocalDate` object to pass to `YearWeek.from`.  
)                                        
.toString()                                       // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format: yyyy-Www
```

> 2018-W13

## Details

When you fetch your `Date` type from H2 as a [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), convert to a `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = mySqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

You can interrogate for the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard [definition of a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) where week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the year, and runs Monday-Sunday.

```
int weekNumber = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
```

Extract the year.

```
int year = ld.getYear();
```

Assemble your standard ISO 8601 string.

```
String output = year + "-W" + String.format( "%02d ", weekNumber );
```

Even easier is to use the [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class from the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

```
String output = YearWeek.from( ld ).toString() ;
```

### JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database. No need to over use java.util or java.sql date-time classes again.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;  // Capture the current date as seen in the wall-clock used by the people in a certain region (a time zone).
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).